# Scikit-learn with different outputs calculation

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I used sudo `apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib python-sklearn` for scikit-learn installation on rPi3 but an old version was applied!

This old version installed (v. 0.18) got output results complete different over same algorithms if compare with Windows or Mac installation (v. 0.20.1)

Windows/MAC results:
R2: 0.992
MSE: 0.011
SEP: 0.104
RPD: 11.509

Raspberry results:
R2: -19.00065
MSE: 28.60711
SEP: 5.34856
RPD: 0.22360

The same algorithm use PLSRegression.

Trying to use pip install on rPi3 bring a lot of compilation errors (no way). So, why different results? Is this because the different version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [change log](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html#version-0-20-0), you can see that in version 0.19, changes were made to the `PLSRegression` model.

This would explain the difference, as the default argument is `scale=True`.